# How to Make A New Column Which Contains A List That Contains Number Iteration Based on 2 Column in Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below

[image: Dataframe]

How can I add new column which consists of number from first and final(inclusive) in pandas?
For example like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem on my own
Here is my code

```
df['Final'] = df['Final'].fillna(df['First'])
def make_list(first,final):
    return [x for x in range(first,final+1)]
df['Towers'] = df.apply(lambda x: make_list(x['First'],x['Final']), axis=1)
```